# Where can I read English/Hindi version of Mudgala Purana?

Tags: puranas, translation-request

I want the English/Hindi translation of [Mudgala Purana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudgala_Purana). Where can I find this?

Answer (score 4):

Mudgala Purana is the Uppurana (sub - Purana) which have collection of life stories of lord Ganesha. 
here are few links where you get more information on Mudgala Purana

[PDF [Sanskrit]](https://ia801004.us.archive.org/3/items/mudgalapurana/mudgalapurANa.pdf)

[Wikipidea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudgala_Purana)

[Marathi](http://www.transliteral.org/pages/i120106161238/view)

[Blog](http://theganeshaexperience.com/tag/mudgala-purana/)

[PDF [Eng]](http://cincinnatitemple.com/articles/Ganesha-e-Book.pdf)

for More Purana try link below where you can download the nearby all purana.

[Purana's list](https://vedpuran.net/2011/10/21/ved_puran/)

Comment: The first link is not in English as suggested, but in Sanskrit.

Comment: @GabeHiemstra my bad. I corrected it in solution.

Comment: @rhatwar007 Thanks for correcting. Even though, the Sanskrit edition is indeed a valuable addition. Counting over 1,000 pages, I wonder if this includes a commentary?