# Where can I know about the eight forms of Lord Ganesh from Mudgala purana?

Tags: ganesha, resource, upapuranas

I would like to know where can I find a complete English version of the Mudgala Purana and also the eight forms of Lord Ganesha.

Comment: Partial duplicate of [Where can I read English/Hindi version of Mudgala Purana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14248/where-can-i-read-english-hindi-version-of-mudgala-purana).